# How do I decode and play a .AVI file in SDL 2.0?

Tags: c, video, sdl

The title says about all I want to say. How would I go about implementing software to decode .AVI files on Windows with the combined power of SDL 2.0? If it's not easy, I'll probably hold off on doing it, but I came here to see what the general steps might look like. I'm primarily a C programmer, though I should be able to understand most non-OOP heavy C++. I also have experience with the Win32 API.

**Edit :**

Some quick google searching got me this tutorial with OpenGL and .AVI files on Windows : http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/playing_avi_files_in_opengl/23001/

I only read the first part of it, which was enough to figure out that Mircosoft does indeed have API functions/structures to assist with opening and creating streams from AVI files. This probably won't answer my question completely, since I don't know the first thing about OpenGL and its' functions. I don't have time to study it further right now. I still encourage whomever to post whatever help they want if he/she can.

Comment: It's not trivial, SDL has no direct support for playing video. The deconding itself is the biggest issue. If you have the individual bitmaps for the frames and the audio you could use SDL to play .avi files.

Comment: I knew it had no direct support, but SDL would at least provide multi-threading along with graphics and audio capabilities. All of which win32 provides, but since SDL is cross-platform, it is probably better( and even easier ) to do most of it in SDL if I can. No, I do not have the images and frames. As I said, if it's going to be difficult enough to take a long time to figure out, I'm not going to attempt it right now.